# Rotate object smoothly in any direction using slider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to rotate objects on the x, y, and z axis but my objects are not rotating on the y and z axis. I am using one slider with to rotate the objects in the x plane but now wanted to rotate the object in y and z too. So what changes should be made to the existing code to make the objects rotate in the y and z planes?

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
  // Assign in the inspector
  private GameObject objectToRotate;
  public Slider slider;

 // Preserve the original and current orientation
 private float previousValue;
 private float startValue = 0.5f;
 void Awake ()
{
    // Assign a callback for when this slider changes
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener (OnSliderChanged);

    // And current value
    previousValue = slider.value;
}

void OnSliderChanged (float value)
{
    // How much we've changed
    float delta = value - previousValue;
    objectToRotate.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * delta * 360);
    

    // Set our previous value for the next change
    previousValue = value;
}

void Update()
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hitObject;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject))
        {
            objectToRotate = hitObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.gameObject;
            objectToRotate.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetSelected();
        }
    }       
}

  public void Deselect()
 {
    objectToRotate.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetOriginalMaterial();
    objectToRotate = null;
    slider.value = startValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to rotate them all with the same slider?

Comment: with different slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two more references to the other sliders, two `previousValue` variables and `OnSliderChanged` functions.

```csharp
public Slider sliderX, sliderY, sliderZ;
private float previousValueX, previousValueY, previousValueZ;

void Awake ()
{
    // Assign a callback for when this slider changes
    sliderX.onValueChanged.AddListener (OnSliderChangedX);
    sliderY.onValueChanged.AddListener (OnSliderChangedY);
    sliderZ.onValueChanged.AddListener (OnSliderChangedZ);

    // And current value
    previousValueX = sliderX.value;
    previousValueY = sliderY.value;
    previousValueZ = sliderZ.value;
}

void OnSliderChangedX (float value)
{
    // How much we've changed
    float delta = value - previousValueX;
    objectToRotate.transform.Rotate (Vector3.right * delta * 360);
    
    // Set our previous value for the next change
    previousValueX = value;
}

void OnSliderChangedY (float value)
{
    // How much we've changed
    float delta = value - previousValueY;
    objectToRotate.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up * delta * 360);
    
    // Set our previous value for the next change
    previousValueY = value;
}

void OnSliderChangedZ (float value)
{
    // How much we've changed
    float delta = value - previousValueZ;
    objectToRotate.transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward * delta * 360);
    
    // Set our previous value for the next change
    previousValueZ = value;
}


public void Deselect()
{
    objectToRotate.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetOriginalMaterial();
    objectToRotate = null;
    sliderX.value = startValue;
    sliderY.value = startValue;
    sliderZ.value = startValue;
}
```